# Restore SP 2003 backup (.fwp) files to SP 2007

Tags: restore, 2003

Scenario - My team was using SP 2003 , which crashed, we have back up in .fwp format. We need to restore the backup to SP 2007.

I have already tried to extract all the fwp files and ran Smigrate Utility after creating a default page in SP 2007. Utility neither throws any error nor restores the data.

I have read that if there are multiple .fwp file created while taking backup we can mention the file which contains the manifest.xml , utility automatically identifies the  rest of the files, hence I ran the Smigrate as given below.

```
Smigrate.exe -r -w http://team-site -f D:\backup\data.fwp
```

Here also utility neither throws any error nor restores the data.

Has anyone faced such issues, please help with expert advise.

Answer (score 1):

This utitly not supporting to migrate the sites between different SharePoint version i.e from 2003 to 2007.

In you case, you have to build a 2003 farm restored your backup their, from their you have to migrate the content using the 3rd party tool or using the OOTB migration.

read more here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303420(v=office.12).aspx

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2418ca4b-f544-402b-b060-2cbb78e80c90/migrating-from-2003-to-2007?forum=sharepointadminlegacy

Comment: Thanks Waqas for the response! I have tried to set up the 2003 R2 Sharepoint version , created a blank site , ran the Smigrate Utility the same problem continues, where Smigrate doesnt throw any error nor it restores the site. Please help if anything else I am missing here.